# Is watching shows (shirk/kufr) if they contain various things from different mythology?

Tags: shirk, kufr

If a show contains different creatures like elves, succubi, vampires or ogres from different mythologies and if I don't believe that those creatures are real or they actually exist will I be committing (kufr/shirk) if I watch these shows?

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that watching such figures is haram or leads to shirk? Are they doing something sinful, or encouraging sinful actions? Is it for educational purposes?

Comment: I do believe watching these things are haram and yeah sometimes they do sinful things but I do not get encouraged by them so will it be counted as kufr/shirk?

Comment: Well, if you truly don't agree with any haram actions committed by them; then solely watching such stuff is not committing shirk. But that is not to say that it could be haram (sinful) to watch such stuff, and that depends on MANY factors. The age and mentality of person watching. The actions of such figures, are they doing magic, sexual stuff? All these things must be taken into consideration.

Comment: Yeah sometimes they use magic and other things which Islam doesn't support and I really don't believe or like those things from the bottom of my heart and about sexual stuff i have watched hentais before which  contained a lot of mythological creatures and magics and stuff I also didn't believed those things and I don't watch hentai anymore so did I commited shirk/kufr by watching those shows/hentais in the past?

Answer (score 1):

Watching such stuff is definitely bad for the individual; even if one condemns the viewed action, it still could negatively impact one's subconscious mind without feeling, hence negatively affecting you as a person. And most importantly, it's something that doesn't please Allah Subhanu wa Ta'la. So watching those stuff, especially hentai, is definitely **haram** and forbidden in Islam, as Islam always aims to preserve one's purity and mental clarity, away from filth and sins/shrik. But it is not shirk/kufur since you disagree with such actions. I would suggest you make tawba to Allah The All-Merciful, and Al Hamdulilah that you stopped watching such stuff. I ask Allah to keep you steadfast on your deen.

Comment: P.S. read comments below original question

Comment: Few days ago I just found out that in mythologies elves are believed to be divine beings . Will it still not count as shirk/kufr because I watched these shows or hentai in the past? And what about people who still watch this things? Will they commit shirk/kufr?

Comment: @AlifAlSami Regardless of whether they are believed to be "divine" or not, do YOU ```personally``` believe that they are divine, or in some way godly? I could watch a documentary about Christianity about how they believe that Jesus is god but I definitely don't agree with that, regardless of what they say so I won't be a kafir.

Comment: what if these shows have elements of shirk/kufr in their names or in the names of a certain episode will it fall under the same ruling of haram?